programa para la señora de los tamales
Descripción
Acabas de organizar una enorme fiesta con mil invitados (convenientemente numerados del
al
) y la mayor atracción de la fiesta son los deliciosos tamales. Los invitados a la fiesta deben formarse en la cola y al llegar su turno, la señora de los tamales les dará un tamal. Como los tamales están verdaderamente ricos, muchos de los invitados vuelven a formarse en la cola. Sin embargo, la señora sólo tiene permitido darte un tamal a cada invitado (por cuestiones de presupuesto y para evitar que alguien se quede sin el suyo). Escribe un programa que ayude a la señora a identificar a qué invitados sí debe entregarles un tamal cuando llegue su turno.
Entrada
Un entero
seguido de la descripción de
eventos. Los eventos pueden ser de dos tipos:
FORMA
: se formó el invitado con número
.
ATIENDE: la señora debe atender al invitado al frente de la cola.
Puedes suponer que
, que el número de cada invitado es válido, que los invitados se formarán sólo si en ese momento no están en la cola y que sólo se atenderá a un invitado si la cola no está vacía.
Salida
Para cada evento del tipo ATIENDE, imprimir el mensaje SI TAMAL o NO TAMAL seguido del número del invitado, dependiendo si la señora le debe entregar o no un tamal.
Código
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_INVITADOS 1000
#define TAMAL_BITS ((MAX_INVITADOS + 31) / 32)

typedef struct {
    int cola[MAX_INVITADOS], frente, final;
    unsigned int tamal[TAMAL_BITS];
} Fiesta;

void inicializar(Fiesta *fiesta) {
    fiesta->frente = 0;
    fiesta->final = -1;
    memset(fiesta->tamal, 0, sizeof(fiesta->tamal));
}

void forma(Fiesta *fiesta, int invitado) {
    fiesta->final = (fiesta->final + 1) % MAX_INVITADOS; 
    fiesta->cola[fiesta->final] = invitado;
}

void atiende(Fiesta *fiesta) {
    if (fiesta->frente <= fiesta->final) {
        int invitado = fiesta->cola[fiesta->frente];
        int index = invitado / 32, bit = invitado % 32;
        if (!(fiesta->tamal[index] & (1U << bit))) {
            fiesta->tamal[index] |= (1U << bit);
            printf("SI TAMAL %d\n", invitado);
        } else {
            printf("NO TAMAL %d\n", invitado);
        }
        fiesta->frente = (fiesta->frente + 1) % MAX_INVITADOS; 
    } else {
        printf("NO TAMAL\n");
    }
}

int main() {
    int N, invitado;
    char evento[10];
    Fiesta fiesta;
    scanf("%d", &N);
    inicializar(&fiesta);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        scanf("%s", evento);
        if (strcmp(evento, "FORMA") == 0) {
            scanf("%d", &invitado);
            forma(&fiesta, invitado);
        } else if (strcmp(evento, "ATIENDE") == 0) {
            atiende(&fiesta);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}


Bienvenido. Esto no es omegaup. ¿Cuál es la pregunta y cuál es tu código?

@Mateo     ¿Qué es lo que tengo que corregir para que la salida de mi programa sea correcto?

Pregunta relacionada: Pilas en arreglos y Colas y colas dobles en arreglos
